# How to concatenate multiple rows into a single row and repeate this operation over a big dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm working with a data frame containing 582,260 rows and 24 columns. Each row corresponds to a 24 hours vector length time series, and 20 rows (days) correspond to id_1, 20 to id_2... and so on up to id_N. I would like to concatenate into a single row all the 20 rows of id_1 so that my concatenated time series become a 480 (20 days * 24 hrs/day) vector length, and repeat this operation from id_1 to id_N.

A very reduced and reproducible version of my data frame is shown (ID column should be an index but for iteration purposes I reseted it):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['id1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1], ['id1', 0, 1, 5, 2, 1], ['id1', 3, 4, 5, 0, 0], 
                   ['id2', 1, 1, 8, 0, 6], ['id2', 5, 3, 1, 1, 2], ['id2', 5, 4, 5, 2, 7]],
                  columns = ['ID', 'h0', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4'] )
```

I've tried with the next function to iterate over the rows in the data frame but it doesn't give me the expected output.

```
def concatenation(df):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if df.ix[i]['ID'] == df.ix[i+1]['ID']:
            pd.concat([df], axis = 1)
            return(df)

concatenation(df)
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['id1', 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0], 
                   ['id2', 1, 1, 8, 0, 6, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2, 7]],
                  columns = ['ID', 'h0', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 
                             'h0', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4',
                             'h0', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4'])
```

Is there a compact and elegant way of programming this task with pandas tools?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a column `day`, then create a hierarchical index of `ID` and `day` that then gets unstacked:

```
df['day'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['ID','day'])
res = df.unstack()
```

Intermediate result:

```
      h0       h1       h2       h3       h4      
day    0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  2  0  1  2
ID                                                
id1    1  0  3  1  1  4  3  5  5  4  2  0  1  1  0
id2    1  5  5  1  3  4  8  1  5  0  1  2  6  2  7
```

Now we flatten the index and re-order the columns as requested:

```
res.set_axis([f"{y}{x}" for x, y in res.columns], axis=1, inplace=True)
res = res.reindex(sorted(res.columns), axis=1)
```

Final result:

```
     0h0  0h1  0h2  0h3  0h4  1h0  1h1  1h2  1h3  1h4  2h0  2h1  2h2  2h3  2h4
ID                                                                            
id1    1    1    3    4    1    0    1    5    2    1    3    4    5    0    0
id2    1    1    8    0    6    5    3    1    1    2    5    4    5    2    7
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Stef, I tried your solution in the original dataframe but it raises the `ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow
` error. I think is because of its size. I'll try to look to a solution for this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @Stef, your solution worked very good. I just had to make some adjustments, but it really helped me a lot! Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome - would you mind [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict(list)` and `.extend()` method to store all the values in exact order and to create the same output as you defined.

But this would require you to do a crude loop which is not recommended for large dataframes.

Comment: Sorry but could you be more specific?
Thank you.